# Unity Cloning Object Makes Permanent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create objects through code. However, these are clones. How can I make an object that I have instantiate permanent?

Comment: You'd have to provide a lot more context for anyone to be able to help you. What have you tried? What does "permanent" mean (I'm no Unity expert so maybe I'm just clueless)? Please update your question and take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

By "permanent" I am assuming you mean you want the object to persist through scene loads. To do this, simply use `Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(yourObject)` after instantiating the object.